# How to install Magento 2.0 extension?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Can someone give me a step-by-step installation guide for extensions from zip files for Magento latest version?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the extension file in your magento 2 Directory
2. (if not executable permission for magento CLI.. got to YOUR_INSTALLATION_DIR) (sudo ) `chmod +x bin/magento`
3. .`/bin/magento module:enable` NAMESPACE_MODULENAME
4. `./bin/magento magento setup:upgrade`

   **Update** after comment:

   - step 3: The NAMESPACE_MODULENAME means there should be this folder structure like `app/code/NAMESPACE/MODULE/` inside your magento installation folder. Some extension don't have this but many files and folders like Model, Block... and a `composer.json`. If so 
     open composer.json and look on **name** at the top

     "name": "TEST/MODULE"
     ....

if so you create  dir like `app/code/TEST/MODULE` and copy content of zip file inside Module. This steps(3) simply enable the module, same as adding xml file in app/etc/modules/TEST_MODULE.xml in magento 1x.

- Step 4. upgrade the database scheme of extension.

Comment: Can you explain last two steps

Comment: Rather than Namespace_Modulename, it makes sense to have `VendorName_ModuleName`, also pay attention to CamelCase in naming modules.
Also, setup:upgrade not only upgrades schema, but if it is a new module, it first installs schema as well as data and then runs upgrade schema as well as data.

Comment: Thank you Maddy. @user3918128 if it helped and solved problem can you please close it?

Answer (score 0):

[Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/#/individual-contributors) provide very detail instruction on how to set up extensions. (You can also filter through each version on top)

https://devdocs.magento.com/#/individual-contributors

I found this guy's Youtube video to be super helpful. Not to mention his cute accent. :)

Course from [Magento U](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4MzdqVV9V8&list=PLY_U2aJagyKQN58Cw7Tecm-sgPneeyJm8)
[Andy Myers](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC45Sfn1ljPztowl0kB7yJbw)

Hope this helps!